# Unable to get variable from htaccess rewrite url

Tags: .htaccess

I am unable to get variable from htaccess url

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

#redirect localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=1&album_id=1&action=contacts to localhost/apnaujjain/1/1/contacts.html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&album_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&album_id=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Now my final url should be

```
loalhost/apnaujjain/1/1/contacts.html and all parameters should be get individualy
```

Now url is creating ok but I am unable to get album id via url its coming with third variable action but not album id. Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex in 2nd rule needs some tweaking:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&album_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2/%3.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&album_id=$2&action=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+.+?\.php\?page_id=([^\s&]+)&action=([^\s&]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule . %1/%2.html? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^./]+)\.html$ page.php?page_id=$1&action=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: yeah that's true but my regex is really not that good but still I try to do it

Comment: no same problem $_GET['action'] gets 1/contacts.html and album id is still undefined

Comment: That rule worked fine in my testing. Show your complete .htaccess in question also what does `www.localhost/page.php?page_id=1&album_id=1&action=contacts` get redirected to?

Comment: Sorry its still not working even now the previous things stopped working

Comment: both type of url not working now its showing error 500 server error

Comment: ok sorry here it is                                                                  localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=2&action=ujjaincity                                                                                            localhost/apnaujjain/page.php?page_id=2&album_id=5&action=ujjaincity

Comment: yeah its perfect thanks a lot but still I am tring one last thing that will solve my problem one sack for all I want my url like localhost/apnaujjain/contacts.html in all cases even the number of parameters get increasing but url should be same I mean all parameter should hide except action and in that case action will be the first parameter and after all parameters will hide but I still all parameters should be available in get method, IS IT POSSIBLE?

Comment: No that's not possible, if URL doesn't have a dynamic value e.g. page_id then your GET array can't get it.